# SSRS Action Expression - open a new page using a field value as a url

Tags: url, reporting-services, expression, action, new-operator

I have a table of urls which represent saved PDFS and are displayed in an SSRS report.  I made this field clickable and the action opens the pdf in the same window which allows me to save the pdf to my desktop.  But when I hit the windows back button I have to reenter the parameter.

I prefer to click on the field and it open in a new window.  In fact, I would love to be able to click one button and open all the urls in a new window or at least more than one.

I can't seem to get the syntax right to even open 1 url in a new window.

Help!  What is wrong with my syntax?

="javascript:void(window.open('Fields!Standard_view_PDF.Value & "', '_blank'))"

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the link in the report. Here is an example link that I tried to click on: https:trp250.it.trc.edu/pdf/14040-nbill.pdf – The actual pdf is generated by another application when the link is clicked on rather than an existing file on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the link that it is a file to open.

Try this instead.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('file:"+Fields!Standard_view_PDF.Value+"','_blank'))"
```

Comment: I think you also solved the other problem. The OP had not concatenated the field value into a valid string .